# Unit conversion tables macro/command

Tags: siunitx

Conversion tables are useful converting units from system to another. For example, to convert 1 m^2/s to m^2/hr, we write:

[image]

I usually generate this using `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
     \SI{1}{m^2} & \SI{60}{s}  & \SI{60}{min} \\ \hline
      \si{s}    & \si{min}    & \si{hr}
    \end{tabular} = \SI{3600}{m^2/hr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

My question is: how to create a command/macro/package to do this automatically as follows:

1. I will type the units in sequence; e.g. `\conv{1 m^2/s -> 60 s/min -> 60 min/h}` to give the required table.
2. The table should be expandable, that is, it can accommodate as many conversions as needed.
3. An option to cancel out successive units, for example the `s` and `s`, and the `min` and `min` in each adjacent cell.

Comment: My first idea: Nice, but not easy -- perhaps with `expl3` doable (and since `siunitx` is an `expl3` package anyway ... ;-)

Comment: Excellent wish. I could use this macro! Several questions: Why not `*` in macro syntax instead of `->`? It really is multiplication. Why not write a product of fractions rather than using a table, or make the table resemble such a product? Will you want more complicated unit arithmetic - e.g `($/person)/year`?

Comment: @EthanBolker Any symbol will do. I was using the `menukey` package syntax. The format I used above is taken from a famous chemical (see page 9+ here: http://197.14.51.10:81/pmb/CHIMIE/Elementary%20Principles%20of%20Chemical%20Processes%203.pdf)

Comment: @jak123: Are there always units in fractions, like `m^2/s` etc?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The first entry can be anything (fractions or not), the remaining will have fractions.

Comment: @jak123 cancelling with `siunitx` requires the unit macros as input AFAIK… would that be a problem?

Comment: @clemens: Can `siunitx` autocancel units?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it works together with the `cancel` package but does not cancel units automatically

Comment: @clemens I was thinking of something similar to the `cancel` package. It can be added as a command, for example: `\conv{1 m^2/s -> 60 \x s/\x min -> 60 \x min/h}, where \x is for cancel.

Comment: @jak123 to see what I meant please have a look at the result of `\si{\cancel m^2}` vs `\si{\cancel\metre\squared}` (using both `siunitx` and `cancel`)

Comment: @clemens I see, but `\cancel{\si{m^2}}` gives the desired effect but produces an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is near to what you want. The final unit is computed from the first numerator and the last denominator. If it's not so, you have to specify the unit in the optional argument to `\conv`, like

```
\conv[<settings>]{...}[<unit>]
```

The conversion is automatically computed from the values in the numerator and the denominator. The leading optional argument is for `siunitx` settings, which will affect both the left-hand side and the right-hand side. The command can go in text or math mode without any change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,siunitx,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\conv}{O{}mo}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \sisetup{#1}
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {
    \jak_conv:nn { #2 } { \jak_conv_first_last: }
   }
   {
    \jak_conv:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
  \group_end:
 }

\seq_new:N \l_jak_conv_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_jak_conv_output_top_seq
\seq_new:N \l_jak_conv_output_bot_seq
\seq_new:N \l__jak_conv_temp_seq
\tl_new:N \l__jak_conv_temp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jak_conv:nn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_jak_conv_output_top_seq
  \seq_clear:N \l_jak_conv_output_bot_seq
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_jak_conv_input_seq { * } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_jak_conv_input_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__jak_conv_temp_seq { / } { ##1 }
    \tl_set:Nx \l__jak_conv_temp_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l__jak_conv_temp_seq { 1 } }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { ([\d\.]*) (.*) } { \c{\__jak_conv_do:nn}\cB\{ \1 \cE\} \cB\{ \2 \cE\} } \l__jak_conv_temp_tl
    \seq_put_right:NV \l_jak_conv_output_top_seq \l__jak_conv_temp_tl
    \tl_set:Nx \l__jak_conv_temp_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l__jak_conv_temp_seq { 2 } }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { ([\d\.]*) (.*) } { \c{\__jak_conv_do:nn}\cB\{ \1 \cE\} \cB\{ \2 \cE\} } \l__jak_conv_temp_tl
    \seq_put_right:NV \l_jak_conv_output_bot_seq \l__jak_conv_temp_tl
   }
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__jak_conv_do:nn \__jak_conv_do_si:nn
  \begin{tabular}{c *{\int_eval:n { \seq_count:N \l_jak_conv_output_top_seq - 1 }}{|c}}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_jak_conv_output_top_seq { & } \\
  \hline
  \seq_use:Nn \l_jak_conv_output_bot_seq { & }
  \end{tabular}
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__jak_conv_do:nn \__jak_conv_do_extract:nn
  \tl_set:Nx \l__jak_conv_temp_tl
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l_jak_conv_output_top_seq { 1 }
    /
    \seq_item:Nn \l_jak_conv_output_bot_seq { -1 }
   }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__jak_conv_temp_tl { \l__jak_conv_temp_tl }
  \ensuremath
   {
    {}=
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__jak_conv_do:nn \__jak_conv_do_eval:nn
    \SI
     {
      \fp_eval:n
       {
        (\seq_use:Nn \l_jak_conv_output_top_seq { * })
        /
        (\seq_use:Nn \l_jak_conv_output_bot_seq { * })
       }
     }
     { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__jak_conv_do_eval:nn
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 } { 1 } { #1 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__jak_conv_do_extract:nn { #2 }
\cs_new:Nn \__jak_conv_do_si:nn
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 } { \si{#2} } { \SI{#1}{#2} }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \jak_conv_first_last: { \tl_use:N \l__jak_conv_temp_tl }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\conv{1 m^2/s * 60 s/min * 60 min/h}

\medskip

\conv[round-mode=places,round-precision=6]{1 m^2/h * h/60min * min/60s }

\medskip

\conv{299792458 m/s * 60s/min * 60min/h * 24h/d * 365.25d/y}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the computation of the light year is accurate.

### Further version with enhancements

The changes are: in the input, `|` is used for separating numerators and denominators, so that `m/s | h` can be specified without special precautions. Calling `\conv*` will suppress the printing of the final result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,siunitx,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\conv}{sO{}mo}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{ \bool_set_true:N \l__jack_conv_print_bool }
  \sisetup{#2}
  \IfNoValueTF{#4}
   {
    \jak_conv:nn { #3 } { \jak_conv_first_last: }
   }
   {
    \jak_conv:nn { #3 } { #4 }
   }
  \group_end:
 }

\seq_new:N \l_jak_conv_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_jak_conv_output_top_seq
\seq_new:N \l_jak_conv_output_bot_seq
\seq_new:N \l__jak_conv_temp_seq
\tl_new:N \l__jak_conv_temp_tl
\bool_new:N \l__jack_conv_print_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jak_conv:nn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_jak_conv_output_top_seq
  \seq_clear:N \l_jak_conv_output_bot_seq
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_jak_conv_input_seq { * } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_jak_conv_input_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__jak_conv_temp_seq { | } { ##1 }
    \tl_set:Nx \l__jak_conv_temp_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l__jak_conv_temp_seq { 1 } }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { ([\d\.]*) (.*) } { \c{\__jak_conv_do:nn}\cB\{ \1 \cE\} \cB\{ \2 \cE\} } \l__jak_conv_temp_tl
    \seq_put_right:NV \l_jak_conv_output_top_seq \l__jak_conv_temp_tl
    \tl_set:Nx \l__jak_conv_temp_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l__jak_conv_temp_seq { 2 } }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { ([\d\.]*) (.*) } { \c{\__jak_conv_do:nn}\cB\{ \1 \cE\} \cB\{ \2 \cE\} } \l__jak_conv_temp_tl
    \seq_put_right:NV \l_jak_conv_output_bot_seq \l__jak_conv_temp_tl
   }
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__jak_conv_do:nn \__jak_conv_do_si:nn
  \begin{tabular}{c *{\int_eval:n { \seq_count:N \l_jak_conv_output_top_seq - 1 }}{|c}}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_jak_conv_output_top_seq { & } \\
  \hline
  \seq_use:Nn \l_jak_conv_output_bot_seq { & }
  \end{tabular}
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__jak_conv_do:nn \__jak_conv_do_extract:nn
  \tl_set:Nx \l__jak_conv_temp_tl
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l_jak_conv_output_top_seq { 1 }
    /
    \seq_item:Nn \l_jak_conv_output_bot_seq { -1 }
   }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__jak_conv_temp_tl { \l__jak_conv_temp_tl }
  \bool_if:NT \l__jack_conv_print_bool
   {
    \ensuremath
     {
      {}=
      \cs_set_eq:NN \__jak_conv_do:nn \__jak_conv_do_eval:nn
      \SI
       {
        \fp_eval:n
         {
          (\seq_use:Nn \l_jak_conv_output_top_seq { * })
          /
          (\seq_use:Nn \l_jak_conv_output_bot_seq { * })
         }
       }
       { #2 }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__jak_conv_do_eval:nn
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 } { 1 } { #1 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__jak_conv_do_extract:nn { #2 }
\cs_new:Nn \__jak_conv_do_si:nn
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 } { \si{#2} } { \SI{#1}{#2} }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \jak_conv_first_last: { \tl_use:N \l__jak_conv_temp_tl }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\conv{1 m^2|s * 60 s|min * 60 min|h}

\medskip

\conv[round-mode=places,round-precision=6]{1 m^2|h * h|60min * min|60s }

\medskip

$\conv{299792458 m|s * 60s|min * 60min|h * 24h|d * 365.25d|y}$

\medskip

$\conv*{299792458 m|s * 60s|min * 60min|h * 24h|d * 365.25d|y}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great. Few comments: (a) when a number appears i the denominator no space is added between the number and unit, (b) if it is difficult to make the calculations based on values on both the numerator and denominator, can the optional argument take the values and its unit instead of the unit only? (c) Can we make the command work in math mode?

Comment: @jak123 Now it should be as you like it.

Comment: Excellent. Just one last modification, is there a way to suppress printing the results (from the equal sign and forward) in case one doesn't wish to show it. Also, if one writes 1 m.s/h, for example, it is ok. However, 1 (m/s)/h, is  not. Finally, I think it is worth it to release this as a package. Thanks again.

Comment: @jak123 For `(m/s)/h`, use `{(m/s)}/h`; or, changing the macros, input the conversion factors as `60s|m` or `m|60s`; in this way, slashes can be used without protection. The printing of the result can be easily suppressed.

Comment: but the syntax with `*` suggests there is commutativity which is not the case as the final unit is composed by simply taking the first numerator and last denominator...

Comment: @jfbu It's just a separator and can be easily changed to `->` if you prefer.

Comment: Many thank @egreg, this keeps getting better. I don't want to be too greedy, but one final comment: I tried to used `per-mode=fraction` to get the final result in fraction format, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @jak123 `\si{m/s}` would not honor `per-mode=fraction` anyway. So you have to use the trailing optional argument; the first `\conv` should have `\conv[per-mode=fraction]{...}[\square\metre\per\hour]`

Answer (score 4):

This splits the list according to the syntax  `number;units->number;units` etc. and displays the figure result in the end as well as the units in the table, but **not** the final unit (I've no clue for that at the moment!)

Use the optional argument to set the correct final unit!

It's absolutely not failsafe!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__unitconv_unit_seq

\seq_new:N \l__unitconv_numbers_seq

\cs_new:Nn \unitsplit:n {% 
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpc_seq {/} { #1 }
\seq_set_eq:NN \l_tmpd_seq \l_tmpc_seq
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpd_seq { \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpc_seq }
\si{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpc_seq {2}}
}

% Weird splitting
\cs_new:Nn \numberunit_split:n {
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {;} { #1 }
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpc_seq {/} { #1 }
\seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
\seq_set_eq:NN \l_tmpd_seq \l_tmpc_seq
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpd_seq {
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpc_seq \l_tmpb_tl 
} % remove the number from the entry
\si{\l_tmpa_tl \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1}} % display first entry
}

\cs_new:Nn \numbersplit:n {%
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {;} { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \l__unitconv_numbers_seq {\l_tmpa_tl} %{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1}}
  } 
}

\cs_new:Nn \multiply_all_numbers:nn {%
  \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp 1
  \seq_map_inline:Nn #1 {% Multiplication loop
    \fp_gset:Nn \l_tmpb_fp { \fp_eval:n {\l_tmpa_fp * ##1}}
    \fp_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_fp \l_tmpb_fp 
  }
\SI{\fp_use:N \l_tmpb_fp}{#2} % Display the result
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\conv}{ov}{%
\seq_clear:N \l__unitconv_unit_seq 
\seq_clear:N \l__unitconv_numbers_seq 
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l__unitconv_unit_seq {->} {#2}  % store the input first and split it into several parts
\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\seq_count:N \l__unitconv_unit_seq}  % How man input parts do we have?
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l__unitconv_unit_seq {\numbersplit:n {##1}}  % Get the figures
%% Key value interface here later on?
\IfValueTF{#1}{%  Has it an optional argument -> yes
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}  % Store it as the possible unit
}{%
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {unit-to-be-specified}  % Ideally this would be autodetermined!
}
\par
% Display the stuff -> convert later on another macro
\begin{tabular}{*{\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int}{c|}c}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__unitconv_unit_seq {% 
    \numberunit_split:n{##1}  & 
  }% Now multiply all numbers
  \multirow{2}{*}{~=~\multiply_all_numbers:nn {\l__unitconv_numbers_seq} {\l_tmpa_tl }} \tabularnewline 
  \cline{1-\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__unitconv_unit_seq { \unitsplit:n{##1}  & } \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
}



\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\conv{1;m/s -> 60;s/min -> 60;min/h}

\conv{ 60;s/min -> 60;min/h -> 24; h/d}

\conv{ 60;s/min -> 60;min/h -> 24; h/d -> 365;d/y}

\conv[km/s]{ 3000000;km/s -> 60;s/min -> 60;min/h -> 24; h/d -> 365;d/y}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course `\multirow` can be dispensed with, by typesetting the final bit *outside* the tabular.

Comment: @egreg: That's was my first idea, but it's all quite a mess at the moment, so it's better to mess it up completely

Comment: I think the numerators (top line entries in the table) all have an extra `/whatever`. Compare the OP's specified output.

Comment: @EthanBolker: Yes, you're right. I used the wrong list internally. I'll update

Answer (score 3):

Here is a toy version very similar I think to @egreg's approach, except that it does not use any package and furthermore  *that the final unit is obtained by canceling units both in numerator and denominator, independently of the orders in which they appear* (the two examples below suggest that the final unit is built from the first numerator and last denominator, but it is much more general than that). However it has annoying limitations:

1. limited to integers
2. prone to arithmetic overflow !

To overcome 1., I would need to write a routine to gather the numbers appearing in front of the units, but I don't know the allowed format. This is what is done in @egreg's answer with the help of `l3regex`.  Here, we just do a basic `TeX` count assignment.

And for 2., any math engine will do. Thus my baby proposal is just to show what one can do with no package.

A third limitation is that it requires each item to be of the shape `number unittop/unitbottom`. The code could be extended to allow items of the shape `number unit` with no slash.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
% \conv{1 m^2/s -> 60 s/min -> 60 min/h}

\makeatletter
\def\zapspaces #1 #2{#1#2\zapspaces }

\def\conv #1{\begin{center}
    \count255 1
    \let\conv@rowi\empty
    \let\conv@rowii\empty
    \let\conv@tops\empty
    \let\conv@bots\empty
    \def\conv@format{\@gobble}%
    \let\JAK\relax\let\JBK\relax
    \conv@ #1->\JAK}

\def\conv@ {\afterassignment\conv@a\count\z@=}

% I will assume that we systematically have unit/unit
% this could be modified
\def\conv@a #1->{\multiply\count255 by \count\z@
                 \conv@b #1/}

\def\conv@b #1/{\edef\conv@utop{\zapspaces #1 \@gobble}\conv@c }

\def\conv@c #1/{\edef\conv@ubot{\zapspaces #1 \@gobble}\conv@d }

\def\conv@gobtilJAK #1\JAK {}

\def\conv@d #1{\edef\conv@rowi{\unexpanded\expandafter{\conv@rowi}%
                    &\noexpand\SI{\the\count\z@}{\conv@utop}}%
               \edef\conv@rowii{\unexpanded\expandafter{\conv@rowii}%
                    &\noexpand\si{\conv@ubot}}%
               \edef\conv@format{\conv@format |c}%
               \edef\conv@tops {\unexpanded\expandafter{\conv@tops}%
                               \JAK{\conv@utop}}%
               \edef\conv@bots {\unexpanded\expandafter{\conv@bots}%
                               \JBK{\conv@ubot}}%
               \conv@gobtilJAK #1\conv@q \JAK
               \afterassignment\conv@a\count\z@=#1}

\def\conv@q\JAK\afterassignment\conv@a\count\z@=\JAK
{%
    \edef\conv@value {\the\count255}%
    \let\conv@@bots\conv@bots
    \let\conv@bots\empty
    \def\JBK ##1{\let\conv@@tops\conv@tops
                 \let\conv@tops\empty
                 \def\conv@tmpbot{##1}%
                 \def\conv@keepperhaps{\expandafter\def\expandafter\conv@bots
                                \expandafter{\conv@bots\JBK {##1}}}%
                 \conv@r}%
    \conv@@bots
    \conv@finish
}

\def\conv@r 
{%
     \def\JAK ##1{\def\conv@tmptop {##1}%
                  \ifx\conv@tmptop\conv@tmpbot
                      \let\conv@keepperhaps\empty
                      \def\conv@tmpbot{\NONE}%
                  \else
                      \expandafter\def\expandafter\conv@tops
                                  \expandafter{\conv@tops\JAK {##1}}%
                  \fi}%
     \conv@@tops
     \conv@keepperhaps
}%

\def\conv@finish
{%        
    \def\JAK ##1{##1 }%
    \def\JBK ##1{##1 }%
    \expandafter\tabular\expandafter{\conv@format}%
       \expandafter\@gobble\conv@rowi \\ \hline
       \expandafter\@gobble\conv@rowii
    \endtabular
    \space= \SI{\conv@value}{\conv@tops/\conv@bots}
    \end{center}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% \begin{center}
%     \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
%      \SI{1}{m^2} & \SI{60}{s}  & \SI{60}{min} \\ \hline
%       \si{s}    & \si{min}    & \si{hr}
%     \end{tabular} = \SI{3600}{m^2/hr}
% \end{center}

\conv{1 m^2/s -> 60 s/min -> 60 min/h}

% can't do that !
%\conv{299792458 m/s * 60s/min * 60min/h * 24h/d * 365.25d/y}

\conv{ 60 s/min -> 60 min/h -> 24  h/d -> 365 d/y}
\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image: Blockquote]